# slack get message sender name for messages return from conversation.history api

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I am calling slack API(conversations.history) to get channel messages. I want to retrieve sender name in message response. how can i get it?

below is my message response:

```
{  "client_msg_id": "0e19ca7d-1072-4f73-a932-9ec7fa9956de",
          "type": "message",
          "text": "Yeah good edge case, I would agree, just mentioning \" no data found\"",
          "user": "U01JW9D10PQ",
          "ts": "1642216920.001100",
          "team": "T01K38V9Q7M", blocks:[]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **conversations.history** API doesn't return user information (just user id), you may need to [fetch each user from the channel history](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info/code), see an example code:

| Get Slack channel history users | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70719141) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const channelId = 'C02TSNCQ2Q2';
const channelHistory = await client.conversations.history({
  channel: channelId,
});

// Get the user ids from the history and populate an array with the user details
const userList = [];
for await (let message of channelHistory.messages) {
  const userAdded = userList.find(user => user.id === message.user);
  if (!userAdded) {
    const response = await slackClient.users.info({
      user: message.user,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const { id, name, real_name, profile, is_bot } = response.user;
      userList.push({ id, name, real_name, profile, is_bot });
    }
  }
}

console.log(`There are ${userList.length} users in the channel conversation:\n${userList.map(user => `${(user.is_bot ? '' : '')} ${user.name}`).join('\n')}`);
```

Comment: How can i get username in mentioned message instead of user id for e.g.  "text": "What is the hour of the pearl, <@U0LAN0Z89>?",- @rub

Comment: Yup, you can do that with my code example, when you're iterating each message to fetch the user, just replace the user id with the real name of it:  message.text = message.text.replace(/<(.*)>/, name);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user id returned from the `user` key to make a call to [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) after you receive that payload.